# how to implement BinarySearchTree on shared_ptr in c++?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, shared-ptr

I don't understand how can I use shared_ptr to implement BinarySearchTree. This is my code.

```
template<class T>
class Element{
    public: 
        T value;
        shared_ptr<Element> left;
        shared_ptr<Element> right;
        Element(T value);
};

template<class T>
Element<T>::Element(T value)
{
    this.value = value;
    this.left = NULL;
    this.right = NULL;
}

template<class T>
class BinarySearchTree{



    public:
        Element<shared_ptr<T>> root;
        BinarySearchTree(T value);
        bool insert(Element<shared_ptr<T>> element);
        bool find(T element);
        bool erase(T element);
        T & min();
        T & max();
};

template<class T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree(T value)
{
    this -> root(new Element<T>(value));
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BinarySearchTree<int> bst(3);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my problem :

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

error C2512: 'Element' : no appropriate default constructor

Please, help me.

Comment: *Why* would you use `shared_ptr` to implement a binary search tree? Under what circumstances do you expect to have shared ownership of a node?

Comment: @JerryCoffin you could implement efficient subtree retrieval and manipulation using some kind of reference counting to avoid node copying. std::shared_ptr is a good starting point to do that.

Comment: You could, and if that's his real intent, it's (at least sort of) fine. That's largely why I asked questions instead of just saying: "use unique_ptr"--it's barely possible his choice of `shared_ptr` makes sense (but sufficiently unlikely to be worth asking about in any case, IMO).

Answer (score 0):

`root` should be a pointer to an element, not an element containing a pointer

```
shared_ptr<Element<T>> root;
```

and you initialise it in the initialiser list, not the constructor body

```
template<class T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree(T value) :
    root(new Element<T>(value))
{}
```

You should probably use `unique_ptr` rather than `shared_ptr`, to enforce the single-ownership semantics of a tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works! .But now I have other problem, I can't use this pointer. Intelisense doesn't see field of Element. How can I use it? root->left and root.left doesn't work. Please help me!

Comment: @Tasmanski: `root->left` should work. What error does it give you?

Comment: Thank you very much. I suggested that IntelliSense didn't see field of my class Element. But it works! I don't have any error.. It was my mistake .. Sorry..

Comment: Now I have a similar problem. temp -> left(new Element<T>(value)); "error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments". What is wrong?

Comment: @Tasmanski: You're trying to call the pointer as if it were a function. Presumably, you're trying to assign a pointer to it; that would be `temp->left.reset(new Element<T>(value));` or `temp->left = make_shared<Element<T>>(value);`

Comment: +1. @Mike: it works!. I wonder how I can remove(T element)? Have I use reset() method? Example: temp->left.reset() ? Is it equal: delete temp->left ?

Comment: @Tasmanski: Yes, `reset()` with no argument will empty that pointer, deleting the object if there are no other pointers sharing ownership with it.

Comment: I have a small question... I need return reference to min element in my tree. Have I use get() method to return reference of this object? Example: temp->left.get() ?

Comment: @Tasmanski: `left.get()` returns a pointer; `*left` returns a reference; alternatively, you could return a copy of the shared pointer.

Comment: I can't remove element . There are other pointers sharing ownership with it... What should I do?

Comment: @Tasmanski: You can remove it from the tree by resetting it's parent's pointer to it. Whether or not that's the right thing to do depends on why you have other pointers owning it, and is a design issue beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @ Mike: I do not know why the erase method removes the entire tree instead of element. This is my code. Please help me !! :( [link](http://pastebin.com/DMdPT1pb)

Answer (score 0):

Consider `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`

`std::shared_ptr` is good when ownership is in question and there are likely to be multiple owners

`std::unique_ptr` is more your use case - you have a single known owner and want to offload memory management to the standard library.